# rake aborted! Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems, railstutorial.org

I'm new to Rails. Everything was OK till I change my Gemfile to be able to use heroku. I have pg in my Gemfile but I still get this error while running `bundle exec rake test`

I cannot use rails console either.

```
    rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:411:in `maintain_test_schema!'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/rihanna/workspace/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
/home/rihanna/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:261:in `block in replace_gem'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:411:in `maintain_test_schema!'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/rihanna/workspace/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
/home/rihanna/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `require'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/home/rihanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
```

and this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

#gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.18.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the below

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

by this

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pg'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

For development and test you need `gem pg`  for postgresql adapter instead of `gem sqlit3`

Comment: I got this error after running bundle update: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: pg (>= 0) and pg (= 0.18.1)
So I add  gem 'pg',             '0.18.1'                     instead of pg. But now I get this error:  Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (= 0.18.1) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.

Comment: Isn't this the other way around? You need gem pg for production and gem sqlit3 for development.

Comment: Hanna did you solve it? I had the same problem and I solved just specifying the pg version into the gemfile. I also had to delete gemfile.lock and run a bundle update before everything start working. By the way, you DO NOT need pg for dev and testing, and use it in production only is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

similar problems, despite Gemfile being correct (pg in produciton, and sqlite in dev, database.yml had postgresql). bundle refused to pickup pg gem.

i was scripting the creation of heroku instance, so all this was on the cli

My solution

- explicitly add postgress add-on (`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app <myappname>`). this seems to force it to create DATABASE_URL early enough (`Created postgresql-xxxxxxx-9999 as DATABASE_URL`). at which point bundle seemed to work.
- something else I considered / tried and have kept for each environment creation, is to make sure you force variables to be set ASAP in the process `heroku config:set --app  <mayappname> RAILS_ENV=production`